# Windows CMD delete directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dir

I'm in D:\User Profiles\ and I need to delete directorys located in

```
D:\User Profiles\---USERNAME---\UPM_Profile\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default
```

Now here's the question. How can I do this dynamic ?
If I type

```
dir /ad /b /s D:\User Profiles\*\UPM_Profile\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default
```

it fails.
---USERNAME--- and *.default needs to be dynamic.
Any ideas `?

Comment: Define what you mean with **dynamic**. Are they parameters for a batch file?

Comment: Do you need the `*` for the username to be dynamic?

Comment: yes, the directory "User Profiles" contains several directorys for usernames like "a1, a2, a3, a4" and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
@echo off
for /d %%i in ("D:\User Profiles\*") do (
   call :remove_dirs %%i
)
goto :eof

:remove_dirs
  echo %1
  for /d %%j in ("%1\UPM_Profile\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles") do rmdir %%j
  goto :eof
```

Comment: The `%~dp1` should be `%~1` to include the user folder, or `%~dpnx1` otherwise `%~dp1` will resolve to d:\user profiles\ right?

Comment: Try it for yourself.  %~dp returns the drive:\path but that's when it has a filespec.  If there is no filespec then the final path element is treated as the filename.  Replace `echo %1` with `echo %~dp1` and see the same folder echoed every time.

Comment: @foxidrive: you are right of course. A `%1` should be enough.